# Algorithm for checking duplicate entry in timetable app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, algorithm, mern

I am trying to make a timetable management app but got stuck in between. Let me share you the code and will discuss accordingly.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { listTeacher } from '../../features/teacherSlice'
import { listClassrooms } from '../../features/classSlice'
import html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js';
import ModalItem from './Modal';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const TimetableItem = () => {

    //redux imports
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    //redux states
    const { teachers, loading, error } = useSelector((s) => s.teacher);
    const { classRooms, loading: classLoading, error: classError } = useSelector((s) => s.classRoom);
    const [assignedTeachers, setAssignedTeachers] = useState([]);

     const handleChange = (e, period) => {
         const teacherId = e.target.value;
         const teacher = teachers.find(t => t._id === teacherId);

         if (assignedTeachers.some(t => t.teacher._id === teacherId)) {
             return;
         }

         const updatedTeachers = assignedTeachers.filter(t => t.period !== period);
         updatedTeachers.push({ period, teacher });
         setAssignedTeachers(updatedTeachers);
    };

   //removes assign teacher - working fine
    const removeTeacher = (assignedTeacher) => {
        const updatedTeachers = assignedTeachers.filter(t => t !== assignedTeacher);
        setAssignedTeachers(updatedTeachers);
    };

    //print function
    const PrintTable = (e, elementName) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const element = document.getElementById(`${elementName}`);
        // create options for the PDF
        const opt = {
            margin: 0.3,
            filename: `${elementName}`,
            image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
            html2canvas: { scale: 5 },
            jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
        };

        // convert the HTML to PDF using html2pdf
        html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save().catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listTeacher());
        dispatch(listClassrooms())
    }, [dispatch])

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container m-auto mt-2">
                <form id='printTimetable'>
                    {classRooms.length == 0 && (<div className='text-red-500 flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen text-xl'>There are no classroom. Please Add class Room(s) first, <Link to='/class' className='text-purple-500 font-bold mx-1'>click here</Link></div>)}
                    {classRooms.map((classRoom, classIndex) => {
                        return (
                            <React.Fragment key={classIndex}>
                                <div id={classRoom.name} className='my-2 border-b-2 border-red-400 border-dotted py-5'>
                                    <div className="classRoom font-bold text-xl m-2">Class = {classRoom.name}</div>
                                    <table className="w-full">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th className="bg-gray-100 border text-left px-8 py-4">
                                                    <span>Periods</span><br />
                                                    <hr />
                                                    <span>Days</span>
                                                </th>
                                                <th className="bg-gray-100 border text-left px-8 py-4">1</th>
                                                <th className="bg-gray-100 border text-left px-8 py-4">2</th>
                                                <th className="bg-gray-100 border text-left px-8 py-4">3</th>
                                                <th className="bg-gray-100 border text-left px-8 py-4">4</th>
                                                <th className="bg-gray-100 border text-left px-8 py-4">5</th>
                                                <th className="bg-gray-100 border text-left px-8 py-4">6</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            {['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'].map((day, dayIndex) => (
                                                <tr key={day}>
                                                    <th>{day}</th>
                                                    {[...Array(6)].map((_, periodIndex) => {
                                                        const assignedTeacher = assignedTeachers.find((t) => t.period === periodIndex + 1 && t.day === dayIndex + 1 && t.classIndex === classIndex + 1);
                                                        return (
                                                            <td key={periodIndex}>
                                                                {assignedTeacher && (
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <div className='text-center font-semibold flex p-2 flex-col'>
                                                                            <p>{assignedTeacher.teacher.name}</p>
                                                                            <p>({assignedTeacher.teacher.subject})</p>
                                                                            <button className='font-bold text-red-500' onClick={() => removeTeacher(assignedTeacher)}>Remove</button>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                )}
                                                                {!assignedTeacher && (
                                                                    <>
                                                                        <select defaultChecked={"Select Teacher"} className="w-full p-2" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, periodIndex + 1, dayIndex + 1, classIndex + 1)}>
                                                                            <option className='hidden' value="Select Teacher">Select Teacher</option>
                                                                            {teachers.map((teacher) => (
                                                                                <option
                                                                                    key={teacher._id}
                                                                                    value={teacher._id}
                                                                                    disabled={assignedTeachers.some(t => t.teacher._id === teacher._id)}
                                                                                    className={`${!assignedTeachers.some(t => t.teacher._id === teacher._id) ? 'bg-green-500' : 'disabled:bg-red-400 bg-red-400 text-black'} font-bold text-base text-white`}
                                                                                >
                                                                                    {teacher.name} {" "}
                                                                                    ( {teacher.subject}{" "})
                                                                                </option>
                                                                            ))}
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </>
                                                                )}
                                                            </td>
                                                        );
                                                    })}
                                                </tr>
                                            ))}
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <button className='button bg-rose-500 rounded text-white text-xl font-sans font-semibold p-1 px-2 my-2 hover:transform hover:scale-105 hover:bg-rose-600 duration-100' onClick={(e) => PrintTable(e, classRoom.name)}>Print</button>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    })}
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TimetableItem
```

so this is the code of timetable app UI. Here I am using `<table/>` tag for making a tabular UI where I have to show time table

here is the output
[image: Output]

## Problem

I want that when ever a teacher is assign the below logic should be verified 1st.
1. check if period of assign teacher is same or not while assigning again if its same then check if days are same or not. Because same teacher can teach on 2 different periods on same day.
2. If Periods are same and days are also same the class should not be same. This app is for multiple classes in a school.
3.If period are not same and days are same then teacher is assignable as it will not overlap each other.

### What I have tried.

I have made a logic for handle change function but its not working.

code=

```
const assignedTeacher = assignedTeachers.find((t) => {
  if (t.period === periodIndex) {
    if (t.day !== dayIndex) {
      return true;
    } else if (t.classIndex !== classIndex) {
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    if (t.day === dayIndex) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

## Expected output

[image: Expected]
In the above image, according to logic I have created. The periods are not same but are on same day so this should be available to assign buts its not. In simple words I am trying to make a logical function which will prevent teacher's overlapping.

[image: Expected]
In the above image, according to logic I have created. The periods are not same but are on same day so this should be available to assign buts its not. In simple words I am trying to make a logical function which will prevent teacher's overlapping.